# How to create a custom binary protocol server?

Tags: java, tcp, binary, protocols

Please advise what should be the best solution to create a custom binary protocol server. The server should accept the communication from multiple devices via a binary protocol over TCP/IP.

Is there any already existing server/framework solution available? I.e. is node.js suitable to solve this problem? The preferred solution would be Java oriented.

Thanks in advance!

Update: the binary protocol is required to reduce the amount of communication data. Any text format for the protocol could too verbose. Moreover the protocol for the device is already specified.

Comment: There is far too many to mention.  Is there any reason it has to be binary?  Would text do as it is easier to work with?  You could just use the libraries built into Java.

Comment: You could just use `ServerSocket` - but this would obviously require you to implement from scratch. Couldn't you just send binary data over HTTP? Base64?

Comment: You say that a text format "could be too verbose", but it's still best to go with one most of the time.  Text formats are much, much easier to test and debug than binary formats, and compressing a text stream with gzip will eliminate much of the overhead.  Selecting a binary format without demonstrated performance problems is usually premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented such a thing some time ago. I used two standard Java API's for that:

1. **java.net** package: java.net.ServerSocket and java.net.Socket should be able to address most of your needs.
2. **java.concurrency** package: for each new connection Socket accepted from a ServerSocket instance you may want to move processing of this connection Socket into another thread and start listening for the next connection using blocking ServerSocket.accept() method again - a kind of producer-consumer pattern implementation. It can be done by publishing the Socket for the new connection into a queue, which is then used to feed thread pool and each thread in this thread pool takes care of the actual connection handling.

Note: sometimes when you are not sure what kind of conversational pattern is going to happen between client and server (which one if them is expected to send data first over TCP/IP for instance) it does make sense to read data from a Socket and write data into the same Socket in separate threads too.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be a combination of `java.net` `Sockets` and `ServerSockets,` threads, and a protocol implementation based on the facilities of `DataOutput` and `DataInput`.